display image from SQL database in html flask
I'm stuck on a displaying an image stored in my SQL database. I have stored the image already and want to display it, in a column of a row I have in html. I have managed to display the byte-data by using {{item['img']}} but I'm struggling to get the image to show.
The code in html is as follows, the div between *** *** is what I need assistance with (I just have a static image there at the moment):
 {% for item in items %}

        <form method="post">
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">

                      ***<div>
                      <img
                      src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-shopping-carts/img1.webp"
                      class="img-fluid rounded-3" alt="Shopping item" style="width: 65px;">
                      </div>***
                      
                      <div class="ms-3">
                        <h5>{{item["name"]}}</h5>
                      </div>
                    </div>

I'm using python flask.the image I attached shows how I want it displayed
Your assistance is highly appreciated as this is my final project for cs.
 ***<div
<img
src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-shopping-carts/img1.webp"
                      class="img-fluid rounded-3" alt="Shopping item" style="width: 65px;"
</div>***


Use a data: URI in the src attribute, instead of a reference to a filename.

Or create a Flask route that returns the byte data, and use the URL of that route in src.
